# Can't compile shared extension on PHP

Tags: javascript, php, c, throws

I have a file with `PHP` extension I've been maintaining for a while now and it has everything in one directory. Then I moved some of the files into a new directory `wb/`, and added the sources appropriately, but compiling the extension throws this error:

```
   Creating library Release_TS\php5ts.lib and object Release_TS\php5ts.exp
wb_winsys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wbError referenced in
 function _wbInit
wb_bitmap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbError
wb_control.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbError
wb_control_toolbar.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbError
wb_generic.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbError
wb_winsys.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wbMalloc referenced i
n function _wbInit
wb_control_toolbar.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbMalloc
wb_font.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbMalloc
wb_generic.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbMalloc
wb_window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbMalloc
wb_bitmap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbMalloc
wb_control.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbMalloc
wb_control_calendar.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbMalloc
wb_control_menu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbMalloc
wb_window.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wbFree referenced in
function _wbSetTimer
wb_winsys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbFree
wb_bitmap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbFree
wb_control.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbFree
wb_font.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbFree
wb_generic.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbFree
wb_bitmap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WideChar2Utf8 referen
ced in function _ReadBitmap
wb_winsys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WideChar2Utf8
wb_control.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wbCallUserFunction r
eferenced in function _wbRefreshControl
wb_window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wbCallUserFunction
Release_TS\php5ts.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\phc-win>
```

This leads me to believe that it isn't being linked properly.

The config looks like:

```
// $Id$
// vim:ft=javascript

ARG_WITH("winbinder", "Include windows GUI support", "no");

if (PHP_WINBINDER == "yes") {
    CHECK_HEADER_ADD_INCLUDE("wb/wb.h", "CFLAGS_INTL")

    EXTENSION("winbinder", "phpwb_bitmap.c phpwb_control.c phpwb_control_listview.c\
    phpwb_control_menu.c phpwb_control_toolbar.c phpwb_control_treeview.c\
    phpwb_draw.c phpwb_export.c phpwb_font.c phpwb_generic.c phpwb_lowlevel.c\
    phpwb_sysdlg.c phpwb_wb_lib.c phpwb_window.c phpwb_winsys.c", "-Iext\\wibinder\\wb");

    ADD_SOURCES("ext\\winbinder\\wb", "wb_bitmap.c wb_control.c\
    wb_control_calendar.c wb_control_html.c wb_control_hyperlink.c\
    wb_control_listview.c wb_control_menu.c wb_control_tab.c wb_control_toolbar.c\
    wb_control_treeview.c wb_draw.c wb_font.c wb_generic.c wb_lowlevel.c\
    wb_sysdlg.c wb_window.c wb_winsys.c")

    AC_DEFINE('HAVE_WINBINDER', 1, 'Include windows GUI support', false);
}
```

The code can be find at https://github.com/stefan-loewe/WinBinder if it's needed, but this should just be a config issue on my part. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You still have to define the linker flags, e.g. `-lwb`.

Comment: Hey, @Jack, submit this as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks! (it wasn't purely that, but it led me linker issues (just the windows format))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as @Jack said in the comments... was to include `-lwb` in the command line. This made the linker work properly and everything is good!

**TL;DR: Don't forget to configure the linker**